# Property 'socials' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I have an angular 2 component with its template file as mentioned below :

**Test.Component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { SampleService, Article, TrackData } from '../../../core';
import { TestService } from '../../shared/social-sharing.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-social-sharing',
  templateUrl: './social-sharing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./social-sharing.component.less']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {  
  socialSharing: Array<any>;  
  constructor(private zone: NgZone,
              private Service1: TestService,
              private Service2: SampleService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setMethod();
  }
   
  public setMethod() {
    this.socialSharing = [{
      containerId: 'social-sharing-preview',
      showLabel: false,
      socials: ['linkedin', 'twitter']
    }];
  }
}
```

**Test.Component.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let social of socialSharing.socials; let i = index;">
    <div class="gig-button-container gig-button-container-{{social}}">
        <div id="social-sharing-preview-reaction{{i}}" class="gig-button-up" title="" alt="">
            <button [attr.data-social]="social"
                class="social-sharing-btn {{socialSharing.showLabel}} ? with-label : ''"
                (click)="socialShare(social)">
                <span class="icon icon_{{social}}"></span>
                <span style="font-size:13px;">{{socialSharing.showLabel}}?"Share on
                  {{social}} | translate":""</span>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On compiling the project I am getting an error as mentioned below :

Property 'socials' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue

Comment: The component's DOM is getting rendered before `setMethod()` is called. Move `this.setMethod();` inside the construcotr and everything should be fine. If you need to have this code executed not in the constructor I sugget you to wrap everything in a `ng-container`, and using a boolean variable, render the html when all the data is set.

Answer (score 0):

The following code fixed the issue:

```
<div id="test">
    <div *ngFor="let item of socialSharing">
      <div *ngFor="let social of item.socials; let i = index;">
        <div class="gig-button-container gig-button-container-{{social[i]}}">
          <div id="social-sharing-preview-reaction{{i}}" class="gig-button-up" title="" alt="">
            <button [attr.data-social]="social[i]" class="social-sharing-btn {{item.showLabel}} ? with-label : ''"
              (click)="socialShare(social[i])">
              <span class="icon icon_{{social[i]}}"></span>
              <span style="font-size:13px;">{{item.showLabel}}?"Share on
                {{social[i]}} | translate":""</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```